# self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I am training a custom ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300  TensorFlow model for object detection using Google Colab with the downgraded version of TensorFlow 1.15.2 because I use to train my model on previous version of TensorFlow i.e. 1.14.0 but due to the latest update to version 2.2.0, I get the strange errors and therefore I can't use the latest version.
Using 1.15.2 version and selection even batch size of 8 I successfully starts the training process but after some time, the training process stops with the following errors.

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

My complete training log is as follows;

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/evaluation.py", line 272, in _evaluate_once
    session.run(eval_ops, feed_dict)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 754, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1259, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1360, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1345, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1418, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1176, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1180, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1359, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Out of range: End of sequence
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
  (1) Out of range: End of sequence
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
     [[Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/non_max_suppression_with_scores_1/NonMaxSuppressionV5/_4683]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Original stack trace for 'IteratorGetNext':
  File "content/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "content/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 110, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 473, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 613, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 714, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1195, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1494, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 754, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1259, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1345, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1426, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 594, in after_run
    if self._save(run_context.session, global_step):
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 619, in _save
    if l.after_save(session, step):
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 519, in after_save
    self._evaluate(global_step_value)  # updates self.eval_result
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 539, in _evaluate
    self._evaluator.evaluate_and_export())
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 920, in evaluate_and_export
    hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 480, in evaluate
    name=name)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 522, in _actual_eval
    return _evaluate()
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 504, in _evaluate
    self._evaluate_build_graph(input_fn, hooks, checkpoint_path))
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1511, in _evaluate_build_graph
    self._call_model_fn_eval(input_fn, self.config))
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1544, in _call_model_fn_eval
    input_fn, ModeKeys.EVAL)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1025, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode))
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/util.py", line 65, in parse_input_fn_result
    result = iterator.get_next()
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 426, in get_next
    name=name)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2518, in iterator_get_next
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 117, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 235, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 416, in first_value_func
    self._metrics = self.evaluate()

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 247, in evaluate
    coco_wrapped_groundtruth, coco_wrapped_detections, agnostic_mode=False)

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 178, in __init__
    cocoeval.COCOeval.__init__(self, groundtruth, detections, iouType=iou_type)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.params = Params(iouType=iouType) # parameters

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 527, in __init__
    self.setDetParams()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 507, in setDetParams
    self.iouThrs = np.linspace(.5, 0.95, np.round((0.95 - .5) / .05) + 1, endpoint=True)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in linspace

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 121, in linspace
    .format(type(num)))

TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.


     [[{{node PyFunc_3}}]]
     [[cond/Detections_Left_Groundtruth_Right/0/_4927]]
  (1) Invalid argument: TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 117, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 235, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 416, in first_value_func
    self._metrics = self.evaluate()

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 247, in evaluate
    coco_wrapped_groundtruth, coco_wrapped_detections, agnostic_mode=False)

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 178, in __init__
    cocoeval.COCOeval.__init__(self, groundtruth, detections, iouType=iou_type)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.params = Params(iouType=iouType) # parameters

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 527, in __init__
    self.setDetParams()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 507, in setDetParams
    self.iouThrs = np.linspace(.5, 0.95, np.round((0.95 - .5) / .05) + 1, endpoint=True)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in linspace

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 121, in linspace
    .format(type(num)))

TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.


     [[{{node PyFunc_3}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 110, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 473, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 613, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 714, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1195, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1494, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 754, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1259, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1360, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1345, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1426, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 594, in after_run
    if self._save(run_context.session, global_step):
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 619, in _save
    if l.after_save(session, step):
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 519, in after_save
    self._evaluate(global_step_value)  # updates self.eval_result
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 539, in _evaluate
    self._evaluator.evaluate_and_export())
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 920, in evaluate_and_export
    hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 480, in evaluate
    name=name)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 522, in _actual_eval
    return _evaluate()
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 511, in _evaluate
    output_dir=self.eval_dir(name))
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1619, in _evaluate_run
    config=self._session_config)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/evaluation.py", line 272, in _evaluate_once
    session.run(eval_ops, feed_dict)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 861, in __exit__
    self._close_internal(exception_type)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 894, in _close_internal
    h.end(self._coordinated_creator.tf_sess)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 951, in end
    self._final_ops, feed_dict=self._final_ops_feed_dict)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1180, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1359, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 117, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 235, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 416, in first_value_func
    self._metrics = self.evaluate()

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 247, in evaluate
    coco_wrapped_groundtruth, coco_wrapped_detections, agnostic_mode=False)

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 178, in __init__
    cocoeval.COCOeval.__init__(self, groundtruth, detections, iouType=iou_type)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.params = Params(iouType=iouType) # parameters

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 527, in __init__
    self.setDetParams()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 507, in setDetParams
    self.iouThrs = np.linspace(.5, 0.95, np.round((0.95 - .5) / .05) + 1, endpoint=True)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in linspace

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 121, in linspace
    .format(type(num)))

TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.


     [[node PyFunc_3 (defined at tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
     [[cond/Detections_Left_Groundtruth_Right/0/_4927]]
  (1) Invalid argument: TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 117, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 235, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 416, in first_value_func
    self._metrics = self.evaluate()

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 247, in evaluate
    coco_wrapped_groundtruth, coco_wrapped_detections, agnostic_mode=False)

  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 178, in __init__
    cocoeval.COCOeval.__init__(self, groundtruth, detections, iouType=iou_type)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.params = Params(iouType=iouType) # parameters

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 527, in __init__
    self.setDetParams()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pycocotools/cocoeval.py", line 507, in setDetParams
    self.iouThrs = np.linspace(.5, 0.95, np.round((0.95 - .5) / .05) + 1, endpoint=True)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in linspace

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 121, in linspace
    .format(type(num)))

TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.


     [[node PyFunc_3 (defined at tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Original stack trace for 'PyFunc_3':
  File "content/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "content/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 110, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 473, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 613, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 714, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1195, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1494, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 754, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1259, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1345, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1426, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 594, in after_run
    if self._save(run_context.session, global_step):
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 619, in _save
    if l.after_save(session, step):
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 519, in after_save
    self._evaluate(global_step_value)  # updates self.eval_result
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 539, in _evaluate
    self._evaluator.evaluate_and_export())
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 920, in evaluate_and_export
    hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 480, in evaluate
    name=name)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 522, in _actual_eval
    return _evaluate()
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 504, in _evaluate
    self._evaluate_build_graph(input_fn, hooks, checkpoint_path))
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1511, in _evaluate_build_graph
    self._call_model_fn_eval(input_fn, self.config))
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1547, in _call_model_fn_eval
    features, labels, ModeKeys.EVAL, config)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1149, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "content/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 570, in model_fn
    eval_config, list(category_index.values()), eval_dict)
  File "content/models/research/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 1045, in get_eval_metric_ops_for_evaluators
    eval_dict))
  File "content/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 426, in get_estimator_eval_metric_ops
    first_value_op = tf.py_func(first_value_func, [], tf.float32)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 513, in py_func
    return py_func_common(func, inp, Tout, stateful, name=name)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 495, in py_func_common
    func=func, inp=inp, Tout=Tout, stateful=stateful, eager=False, name=name)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 318, in _internal_py_func
    input=inp, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_script_ops.py", line 170, in py_func
    "PyFunc", input=input, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

What are the possibilites of getting over this issue, any kind of recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these lines of code immediately after importing Tensorflow in your train.py

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

Comment: What is the reason behind the issue `self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()` ? And how the above lines of code will fix this?